# Python "equal to" and "not equal to"

Tags: python, operators

I was doing a practice question and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong. Seems I was a little confused about how `or` should work.

I'll pass both a range of numbers from 13 - 19:

```
for i in range(13,20):
    func(i)
```

> Function 1

```
def func(n):
    if n == 15 or n == 16:
        pass
    else:
        n = 0
```

> Result 1

```
0
0
15
16
0
0
0
```

So if n is equal to 15 or if `n` is equal to 16, pass. Anything else, make it 0. Makes sense.

> Function 2

```
def func(n):
    if n != 15 and n != 16:
        n = 0
    else:
        pass
```

> Result 2

```
0
0
15
16
0
0
0
```

If `n` is not equal to 15 or 16, make it 0. Else, pass. Again, makes sense.

Here's where I get a little unstuck:

> Function 3

```
def func(n):
    if n == 15 and n == 16:
        pass
    else:
        n = 0
```

> Result 3

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

*I think* the result is due to both conditions for `n` needing to be met; if is equal both 15 **and** 16, pass, else make it zero. I get that.

> Function 4

```
def func(n):
    if n != 15 or n != 16:
        n = 0
    else:
        pass
```

> Result 4

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

If `n` is not equal 15 or `n` is not equal to 16, then it should be zero.

*I think* this means `or` somehow works the same way as `and` in that both conditions must be met, but was wondering if someone more knowledgeable could explain?

Comment: *"If a value is 15 __and__ it is also at the same time 16"* – You show me the value that passes this test, I'll show you a broken computer. Same with the reverse of *"if the value isn't 15 or isn't 16"* - it can't be both those values at the same time, soooo…

Comment: For Function 3, you can never have a situation where a number is both 15 and 16. 

For Function 4, you only need to fulfil one of the two conditions: either a number is not 15 or a number is not 16. Every number fulfils this condition, since every number is either not 15 or not 16.

Comment: @deceze *"the result is due to both conditions for n needing to be met; if is equal both 15 and 16, pass, else make it zero. **I get that.**"* - I got that. Just being thorough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if n != 15 or n != 16:
```

Every number (including 15 and 16) passes this test, so the result will always be `True`. Remember, only one of the conditions needs to be `True` for an `or` statement to evaluate to `True`. Every number is either not equal to 15 **or** not equal to 16.

---

> I think this means or somehow works the same way as and in that both conditions must be met, but was wondering if someone more knowledgeable could explain?

This is not generally the case. You've written a special case where **or** in conjunction with **not** behaves similarly to **and**. (See Maged's answer about *DeMorgan's Law*)

Comment: *"Every number is **either** not equal to 15 or not equal to 16"* that makes it very clear what is going on. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is basically *De-Morgan* law.

~**(a *and* b) = (~a *or* ~b).**